# Swapping digits

Tags: sed, awk

I would like to swap one digit with the previous one:
E.g. 123456 to 214365
How would I do this using sed/awk in bash environment?

Answer (score 6):

```
echo 123456 | sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\2\1/g'
```

Comment: I have 3 columns of digits and I want the above to happen in the middle one only: E.g. BEFORE:254789123456,5306153059630141,639027041150453 AFTER:254789123456,3560510395361014,639027041150453

Comment: Just a small modification to the sed statement will suffice: `echo 254789123456,5306153059630141,639027041150453 | sed 's/,\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/,\2\1/'`

Comment: @Johnsyweb Nope. What he wants is to swap all the pairs of digits within middle number, not just two first digits.

Comment: Oh yes. I feel dumb for not spotting that. I've now posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment on [x13n's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517293/swapping-digits/4517309#4517309), which answers your question, it seems that you want to be more specific about which digits you swap.

I'd use `awk` to swap all pairs of digits in the second column:

```
bash-3.2$ gawk -V | sed -n 1p
GNU Awk 4.0.0

$ echo 254789123456,5306153059630141,639027041150453 | gawk -F',' '
BEGIN {
    OFS=","
}

{
    $2 = gensub(/(.)(.)/, "\\2\\1", "g", $2)
    print
} '
254789123456,3560510395361014,639027041150453
```

You've asked a number of questions about `sed` and `awk`, I'd recommend getting hold of [*sed & awk, Second Edition*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do).

I'd also recommend reading [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s guide to [writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), which will help you get the answer you need when asking such questions.

Comment: Weird, works for me only when I change `\d` to `[0-9]`. `\d` seems to be matching letter `d`, not a digit. Also, awk needs to be gawk in fact, in order to get `gensub` working.

Comment: I see the same behaviour on OSX. Have updated my answer with versions.

Comment: Cool, now your regexp is matching boobs.

Comment: @x13n: Or Homer Simpson's eyes.